# SimpleMappingExceptionResolver vs ExceptionFilter

Tags: spring, exception, servlet-filters

Currently I am working on an application using a custom Servlet Filter to catch all Exceptions:

```
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ExceptionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

and

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

try {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
} catch (Throwable t) {
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            log.error(((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURL());
        }
        log.error("Exception:", t);
        String path = "/error.do";
        request.getRequestDispatcher(path).forward(request, response);
}
}
```

After investigating for some time I have found SimpleMappingExceptionResolver as an easy way to handle exception and view mappings and as I see I can not use both but I can not see any reason to prefer one method above the other one.

I understand that it is easier to map diferent errors to different views using the resolver but we only use one error view, so I am more concerned about perfomance of both solutions, if one of the will be able to handle a broader range of exceptions and such things.

Thanks in advance to all of you Spring experts

Answer (score 0):

To be honest: throwing an exception in one of the most expensive (in terms of perfomance) things you can do in Java. (*Don't get me wrong, this is NO statement against using Exceptions.*). But if you serious run in an performance problem because you need to process to much exceptions with one of that filters, then you definitely have an other really really serious problem.

So in consequence, you should not think to much about runtime performance of the Filter or Resolver. Think more about which one fits better to your project in terms of less code, better understandable code, less bugs, ....

Comment: Indeed my reasoning was the inverse, it should not be handling too much exceptions but instead how much effort is put loading a filter or a Resolver being injected when they will probably do nothing, and if it has a noticeable impact in request that do not throw exceptions.